# Modifiying Nib file without Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, nib, xib

I was wondering if there is any way to directly manipulate the XIB/NIB files without the use of Interface Builder. I know its difficult but is there any way. Can you please tell me how can I do that or the internal structure or the documentations available on it? And will it be feasible or better in any other way.

Regards,

Vivek

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?  All the visual elements of the xib can be programmatically accessed directly in your code.

Comment: i want to be able add components and modify the views dynamically using the xib's xml format.

Answer (score 0):

Xib/Nib files are XML files, you can edit them with every Texteditor.

I wouldn't recomend that tough, if you want more controll over your app, simply create your views Programmatically. A little introduction for doing so might be: http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/29/creating-a-view-programmatically/  further reading to remove nibs completely from your app:http://www.steili.com/wordpress/2009/02/25/building-an-iphone-app-without-interface-builder/

Comment: i m asked to implement some features with the modification of nib file, for which the requirement is not yet available. i m trying to learn even if its possible. where can i find more details about it? have u ever tried modifying one, or can i make an entire app just by the use of nib file in xml format

Comment: To be honest, i never tried to do that. I just leave nibs out of my programs and do everything in code, i think it simplifies things. If you wan't to have dynamic views it's the only way to do so as far as i know, anyways.

Comment: I was looking for a way to make changes or dynamically build applications when some details about the application is provided.
I mean i want to make a dynamic application that will make some changes or create in other application based on some input.